# How to calculate a variable x that produces non-linear results?

Tags: calculus

Sorry I don't have a mathematical background so It is hard for me to put the right words on it.

Let me explain what I am trying to do with an example.

Essentially I want to solve `x` so that it satisfies both situation:

$100 \times x = 0$

$50 \times x = 3$

I would like to know how to solve this type of equation as well as to know the name of the mathematical concepts involved here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)

Comment: Your example requires something impossible.  If x is a number then 100 * x = 0 is only solved by setting x to zero.  But then 50 * 0 = 0 not 3, so you can't satisfy both.  Are you able to give more context, or do you mean that x is a variable, so that in the equation y * x = a, when y = 100, a = 0, and when y = 50, a = 3?

Comment: @MilesB Yes I mean it is a variable because I guess it's the only way it can satisfy both equations. Once I have the formula for `x` I would be able to find out what would be `a` if `y` is 72 for example.

Comment: You need an algebra in which $2\times3=0$.  This could be a group having $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ as a subgroup.

Comment: It's not quite what you've asked for but you might want the straight line that passes through the $(x,y)$ co-ordinates $(100,0)$ and $(50,3)$.  That's $y=6-\dfrac{3x}{50}$ and looks like this:  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/juuiviorep

Comment: @samerivertwice That is what I was looking for, I accepted a similar answer. Thank you so much for helping me figure out the terminology of what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to interpret your question a little differently, since you yourself say that your mathematical understanding is a bit limited. What I think you want is not a variable $x$ but rather some kind of **function** $f$ which for the value 100 gives you 0, and for the value 50 gives you 3. I.e., we have

$$f(100) = 0$$
$$f(50) = 3$$

Now, there are *infinitely* many different functions that would satisfy the two requirements you have. But if we for example stick to the simplest solution, a linear function, the solution would be

$$f(x) = \frac{-3x}{50} + 6$$

From this you can find a new value, for example which one corresponds to 75, by:

$$f(75) = \frac{-3 \cdot 75}{50} + 6 = 1.5$$

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! I knew somehow I was using the wrong words. Thanks for clarifying that. Could you point out to resources that explain this, and would have allowed me to come to this formula by myself?

Comment: Have a look at [this page](https://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/linear_equation/equation-of-a-line-formula.php) which explains slope-intercept form, point-slope form, and standard form as well as other topics. It will be helpful if you review other topics from Algebra 1 again using Khan Academy. Good luck!

Comment: months later, thank you for the resources :D. Question: it should be "-3y" and not "-3x" right?

Answer (score 1):

To find value of a single unknown variable only one equation is adequate.

An extra equation is termed redundant.

You have given two.

The first  equation gives as a solution $x = 0 $

The second equation gives as a solution $x = 0.6$

Both cannot be true at the same time. In other words the
both cannot be simultaneously true.

Comment: This assumes $x$ is a real number.

Comment: From the question it was clear to me that the OP meant only reals.